# How do I create a smooth curve along an edge on this model?

Tags: modeling, game-engine

I am trying to recreate a Toro Lantern, like the ref image below. I am trying to figure out how to create a smooth curve that goes up the neck of the Toro Lantern. I have tried edging a crease on it and subdividing it, but to no avail I cant reach the desired look I'm going for.

[image: This is what I have in Blender.]

[image: This is the reference image I'm trying to recreate.]

Comment: could you please highlight the part you're talking about on the second picture?

Comment: It is the hourglass figure the Toro Lantern creates, I left a white outline in the updated post. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

I would use an actual curve object in combination with a Screw Modifier.

First create a curve that will be one of four curve edges of your final object. Then in Edit Mode make it the shape you want, but also move it away form the origin in a way that will make the origin the center of your final object. (note the orange dot/origin in the gif image)

Then put a Screw Modifier on the curve object. Set the Axis to X, the Angle to 360, and the Steps to 4. Now if you manipulate the curve, all four curved edges change accordingly.

[image]

When you are happy with the shape press <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd> and choose Mesh From Curve/Meta/Surf/Text, which changes your object to a mesh and applies the modifier.

Since the edge curve in your example image highlighted in white actually splits into two edges at some point, you might want to model this part manually as proposed by moonboots. You can select part of the edges of the curve, up to where the split would be split, and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>B</kbd> to bevel the curve and create the split. (in this example the top part would also have to be scaled down manually to make the curve flow nicely)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think you just need to bring some horizontal edge loops and squeeze a bit, like that:

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]